# Import data from SharePoint to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sharepoint-2010, devops, azure-boards

We have migrated to DevOps from SharePoint 2010. We need to Import all the user stories we have in sharepoint to Azure DevOps . Can any one help me with a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your work items and import them into Azure DevOps as **csv files**, as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/185871/view.html).

Here is the detailed documentation for your reference: [Bulk import or update work items using CSV files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops)